# Optimising the Javascript/jQuery code for iPhone browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile

I'm building a website, primarily for mobiles. I had the following jQuery code

```
$(".reg_action").click(function () {
    var action = $(this).attr("id");
    var ele = $(".reg_line.selected");
    var icon = $(this).html();

    if (action == "deepsleep") {
        var color = "#33bb45";
    } else if (action == "sleep") {
        var color = "#99ef96";
    } else if (action == "awake") {
        var color = "#e1f648";
    } else if (action == "up") {
        var color = "#fb0707";
    }

    ele.find(".reg_segment").val(action);
    ele.find(".reg_color").css("background-color", color);
    ele.find(".reg_icon").html(icon);

    // Move on
    ele.removeClass("selected");
    ele.next().addClass("selected");

})
```

I know it might not be the best way all of it, but anyways it is EXTREMELY slow on iPhones - not fully tested, but seems like it is a general problem, even on the newer. I tried making it in JS indstead (again, might not be perfect):

```
function lineAction(action) {

    if (action == "deepsleep") {
        var color = "#33bb45";
    } else if (action == "sleep") {
        var color = "#99ef96";
    } else if (action == "awake") {
        var color = "#e1f648";
    } else if (action == "up") {
        var color = "#fb0707";
    }

    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
    ele[0].childNodes[1].value = action;
    ele[0].childNodes[3].style.backgroundColor = color;

    var classes = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
    classes[0].nextSibling.classList.add("selected");
    classes[0].className = classes[0].className.replace(/\bselected\b/, '');
}
```

But even that does not seem to help. Any suggestions how to speed this up a lot? I've been googling, and it seems like DOM manipulation is just slow on iPhone. Is there a solution? 
Would it for example help to make the 5 states of each line (default, deepsleep, sleep, awake, up) and then just hide/show the one needed? Pageload is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use object with keys to match and the corresponding value to be set as the value of the key. Then the value can be accessed by using the key. e.g. `color[action]`
2. Reuse the cached reference of the DOM element
3. Use `remove` method of `classList` to remove a class from a element, no need of ragex here
4. Instead of using the `click` event, use `touchstart` event

Here is the VanillaJS updated code.

```js
var color = {
  'deepsleep': '#33bb45',
  'sleep': '#99ef96',
  'awake': '#e1f648',
  'up': '#fb0707
};

function lineAction(action) {
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
  ele[0].childNodes[1].value = action;
  ele[0].childNodes[3].style.backgroundColor = color[action];

  ele[0].nextSibling.classList.add("selected");
  ele[0].className.remove('selected');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it might have helped a little bit. But it should be able to be called quickly (by tapping multiple times in a row). It works quite well on ex my HTC One M7, but apparently iOS slows it down.

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard The issue can be of using the `click` event, try binding the `touchstart` event instead of `click`, this will run faster

Comment: At the moment I use ex <div class="reg_action" onclick="lineAction('action')">. How would I make it with touchStart and click on desktops - and should I then go back to jQuery?

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard Yes, yo've to go with jQuery in this case, `if (iPhone) { event = 'touchStart'; } else { event = 'click'; } $('selector').on(event, function() { ...` This is how you can use different event for iPhone broswers and other browsers. Please don't use the code as it is, this is just the algorithm

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This works like a dream!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91165/discussion-between-tushar-and-christian-bundgaard).